# With Bootstrap, can I center a DIV without 'center-block'?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

Here is the page I'm working with for reference: https://sanafoodsystem.com/ShopNow/Food/Breakfast/FlaxPancakes/tabid/131/Default.aspx

You can see that everything is aligned left, when i center the main, outermost div, each is centered within the 6 span column and pulls the columns further apart created a large space in the middle. How can i just center the entire div as is, and not create the large space in the middle? Center-block doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container center-block">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img alt="" src="/portals/0/Images/products/current/BK009-Flax%20Pancakes.jpg" class="dnn-scale-img" />
        <br />
        <p>Made with organic whole wheat with a healthy dose of flaxseed.  They taste almost no different than regular pancakes.  Very simple to make by just placing them in a toaster for approximately 2 minutes.  The blueberries are an excellent source of anti-oxidants. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img alt="" src="/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=VLjbnyMKb3Q%253d&amp;portalid=0" class="dnn-scale-img" />
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATED code to demonstrate my desired effect, but left pancake picture is now too small and resized by being in a smaller column.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img alt="" class="dnn-scale-img" src=
        "/portals/0/Images/products/current/BK009-Flax%20Pancakes.jpg"><br>

        <p>Made with organic whole wheat with a healthy dose of flaxseed.
        They taste almost no different than regular pancakes. Very simple
        to make by just placing them in a toaster for approximately 2
        minutes. The blueberries are an excellent source of
        anti-oxidants.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4"><img alt="" class="dnn-scale-img" src=
    "/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=VLjbnyMKb3Q%253d&amp;portalid=0"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I'm new to programming and still working on how to articulate my problems :) Here is the code the works and what i'm trying to acheive, but the image is now smaller than it needs to be, but shows what I'm going for. Visit the page to see an updated version.

Comment: What does `dnn-scale-img` do? It might be worth checking if it does the same as `img-responsive`

Comment: @Edward The website is DotNetNuke and that is the class for a responsive image. `img-responsive` achieves the same thing i've found as I've tried both.

Answer (score 0):

You nutrition table is quite narrow. This is what is creating the "space" in the middle. I would recommend turning this into a `col-sm-3` as well as adding another to the left of your food image. This will centre the image but keep it right next to the nutrition table.

```
<div class="container center-block">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img alt="" src="/portals/0/Images/products/current/BK009-Flax%20Pancakes.jpg" class="dnn-scale-img" />
        <br />
        <p>Made with organic whole wheat with a healthy dose of flaxseed.  They taste almost no different than regular pancakes.  Very simple to make by just placing them in a toaster for approximately 2 minutes.  The blueberries are an excellent source of anti-oxidants. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img alt="" src="/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=VLjbnyMKb3Q%253d&amp;portalid=0" class="dnn-scale-img" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You will need to add the following CSS, too.

```
.col-sm-3 {
    min-height: 1px;
}

.col-sm-3 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Do you think we can avoid the second CSS rule by applying `img-responsive` class? It [applies `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)

Answer (score 0):

You can't center the container, but you can give it a bigger left and right margin to appear center.

or

I suggest using bootstraps offset feature to offset your columns instead of centering them.

.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting